# Como criar um data frame com vetores de tamanhos diferentes?

Tags: r

O resultado do loop por cada iteração é um vetor. Eu pretendo enviar este vetor para um data.frame para depois exportar o mesmo para Excel.

Basicamente uso a função cbind para enviar cada um dos 10 resultados do meu modelo para um data.frame. Este pequeno exemplo funciona mas apenas se os 10 outputs do modelo tiverem o mesmo número de linhas (isto acontece porque a  função cbind só funciona se as colunas dos data.frames tiverem o mesmo número de linhas). Os vetores que obtenho têm um tamanho diferente. Como posso contornar esta questão?

```
d <- lapply(1:10, function(i) {model <- code
data.frame(model)})
df_total <- do.call(cbind, d)
```

Comment: provavelmente você precisará trabalhar com uma lista, ou criar valores `NA` no seu vetor para que todos os vetores fiquem com o mesmo tamanho para você poder fazer um cbind(). Para uma resposta exata/melhor, favor fazer uma pergunta reprodutível

Answer (score 1):

Como apontado por @guilherme-parreira nos comentários, se sua função retorna vetores com diferentes comprimentos, é melhor usar uma lista. Como não postou um código reproduzível, escrevi de exemplo uma função que retorna um vetor numérico de comprimento aleatório:

```
set.seed(462)

vetor.comp.aleat <- function(...) seq(sample(1:6, 1))

resultado <- lapply(1:3, vetor.comp.aleat)
names(resultado) <- LETTERS[1:length(resultado)]

resultado$C
#> [1] 1 2 3 4
```

*data.frame* é um caso especial de *list* em que todos os elementos são vetores de um mesmo comprimento. Para converter a lista com os resultados, pode primeiro usar `lapply` para mudar os comprimentos de todos os elementos da lista para o maior deles, se valendo dos operadores em R atuarem como funções:

```
data.frame(lapply(resultado, "length<-", max(lengths(resultado))))
#>   A  B  C
#> 1 1  1  1
#> 2 2 NA  2
#> 3 3 NA  3
#> 4 4 NA  4
#> 5 5 NA NA
```